# Stagnation point from complex potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

I just wanted to see if I am doing this right.

$$\Omega(z) = U(z+\frac{a^2}{z})$$

So to find the stagnation point:

$$\Omega'(z) = U(1-\frac{a^2}{z^2})=0$$

Therefore stagnation points occur at:

$z = +/-\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{U}}$

These both occur on the x-axis and I see the stagnation occurs on the circle, so I think it's right but not too sure. Thanks!

Comment: Quick tip first: \pm gives you $\pm$. No need for $U$ in your solution as you must have that $1-a^2/z^2=0$. This means $z=\pm a$.

Comment: @KyleKanos Ah yes of course. And thanks for the tip. :-)